# Unable to generate UUIDs in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

> below is the code block and the error recieved

```
> creating a temporary views 
sqlcontext.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_pay_txn_stage
     USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
     OPTIONS (
       table "t_pay_txn_stage",
       keyspace "ks_pay",
       cluster "Test Cluster",
       pushdown "true"
     )""".stripMargin)

sqlcontext.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW temp_pay_txn_source
     USING org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra
     OPTIONS (
       table "t_pay_txn_source",
       keyspace "ks_pay",
       cluster "Test Cluster",
       pushdown "true"
     )""".stripMargin)
```

> querying the views as below to be able to get new records from stage not present in source .

```
Scala> val df_newrecords = sqlcontext.sql("""Select UUID(),
 | |stage.order_id,
 | |stage.order_description,
 | |stage.transaction_id,
 | |stage.pre_transaction_freeze_balance,
 | |stage.post_transaction_freeze_balance,
 | |toTimestamp(now()),
 | |NULL,
 | |1 from temp_pay_txn_stage  stage left join temp_pay_txn_source source on stage.order_id=source.order_id and stage.transaction_id=source.transaction_id where
 | |source.order_id is null and source.transaction_id is null""")`



org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'uuid()'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.; line 1 pos 7
```

i am trying to get the UUIDs generated , but getting this error.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37232099/2320144

Comment: Thanks @AshrafulIslam , got following error while trying the answer.

scala> val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@39ab2bf3

scala> 

scala> import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.implicits._

scala> val generateUUID = udf(() => UUID.randomUUID().toString)
<console>:46: error: not found: value UUID
       val generateUUID = udf(() => UUID.randomUUID().toString)
                                    ^

Comment: For the meantime i have used workaround of generating UUIDs at source itlself and using them while making scd 2 operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Simple Example How you can generate timeuuid :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext    
val sqlcontext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlcontext.implicits._

//Import UUIDs that contains the method timeBased()
import com.datastax.driver.core.utils.UUIDs

//user define function timeUUID  which will retrun time based uuid      
val timeUUID = udf(() => UUIDs.timeBased().toString)

//sample query to test, you can change it to yours
val df_newrecords = sqlcontext.sql("SELECT 1 as data UNION SELECT 2 as data").withColumn("time_uuid", timeUUID())

//print all the rows
df_newrecords.collect().foreach(println)
```

Output :

```
[1,9a81b3c0-170b-11e7-98bf-9bb55f3128dd]
[2,9a831350-170b-11e7-98bf-9bb55f3128dd]
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37232099/2320144
https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#timeBased--