# How to append List[String] to every row of DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After a series of validations over a DataFrame,

I obtain a List of String with certain values like this:

`List[String]=(lvalue1, lvalue2, lvalue3, ...)`

And I have a Dataframe with `n` values:

```
dfield 1  | dfield 2  | dfield 3
___________________________
dvalue1   | dvalue2   | dvalue3
dvalue1   | dvalue2   | dvalue3
```

I want to append the values of the List at the beggining of my Dataframe, in order to get a new DF with something like this:

```
dfield 1  | dfield 2  | dfield 3 | dfield4 | dfield5 | dfield6
__________________________________________________________
lvalue1   | lvalue2   | lvalue3  | dvalue1 | dvalue2 | dvalue3
lvalue1   | lvalue2   | lvalue3  | dvalue1 | dvalue2 | dvalue3
```

I have found  [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231616/add-a-new-column-to-a-dataframe-new-column-i-want-it-to-be-a-uuid-generator) using a UDF. Could be this correct for my purpose?

Regards.

Comment: do you have a common column for joining? Or you just want to join without common field.?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan just to join without common field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `select` or `withColumn` with `lit` function.

I'd use [lit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lit(literal:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function with `select` operator (or `withColumn`).

> **lit(literal: Any): Column** Creates a Column of literal value.

A solution could be as follows.

```
val values = List("lvalue1", "lvalue2", "lvalue3")
val dfields = values.indices.map(idx => s"dfield ${idx + 1}")

val dataset = Seq(
  ("dvalue1", "dvalue2", "dvalue3"),
  ("dvalue1", "dvalue2", "dvalue3")
).toDF("dfield 1", "dfield 2", "dfield 3")

val offsets = dataset.
  columns.
  indices.
  map { idx => idx + colNames.size + 1 }

val offsetDF = offsets.zip(dataset.columns).
  foldLeft(dataset) { case (df, (off, col)) => df.withColumnRenamed(col, s"dfield $off") }

val newcols = colNames.zip(dfields).
  map { case (v, dfield) => lit(v) as dfield } :+ col("*")

scala> offsetDF.select(newcols: _*).show
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|dfield 1|dfield 2|dfield 3|dfield 4|dfield 5|dfield 6|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| lvalue1| lvalue2| lvalue3| dvalue1| dvalue2| dvalue3|
| lvalue1| lvalue2| lvalue3| dvalue1| dvalue2| dvalue3|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: I have used the **select** function as you suggested. It was so easy of this way:
**dfNew= df.select(lit(array(x)), col(x), col(y), ...)**

Comment: Interesting. What's `array(x)` and `x` and `y`? I'd like to learn from your experience and would appreciate more info how you did that. Thanks.